# How to Cache NSDATA json in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, caching, nsurl

I am using this code to fetch application screenshots of an application from appStore using only appID,

```
    NSString *numericIDStr = appID;
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=%@", numericIDStr];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSData *json = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:0 error:NULL];
NSArray *results = [dict objectForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *result = [results objectAtIndex:0];

myArray = [result objectForKey:@"screenshotUrls"];
```

I managed to cache screenshots by using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/TomThorpe/SDWebImage) and it works perfect, but I noticed that every time that I call this method it delays about 3-4 seconds, and on 3G its even more, about 10-15 seconds.

and other issue that my app crash when not connected to the internet, is there any way to kinda cache this method or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your response(cache) using the following libraries on disk or in memory.

[TMCache](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache)

or [EGOCache](https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache)

Answer (score 0):

Use AFNetworking. It will take one line of code and do the caching for you.

```
  [yourImage setImageWithURL:yourNSUrl];
```

That's it! It does all the caching for you.

Comment: I don't want to cache images, I want to cache NSURL request.